# How to constrain Gradle's "latest.integration" or "latest.release" to a range?

Tags: gradle

Still learning gradle here. Looking for a way to get either the latest "anything" (snapshot/integration or release) or latest must-be-release for a given range, say [1.0,2.0). Is there a way to specify that? Searched everywhere and only found references to either using ranges (which does not seem to allow me to restrict to releases or work with snapshots) or to always keep it entirely open using "latest.integration" and/or "latest.release".

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just updated to the newest Gradle 2.1. That resolved some issues I was having. Otherwise, I discovered the following:

**"latest.integration"** will match the latest anything - snapshot or release, whatever it finds newer.

**"latest.release"** will match the latest release and skip the snapshots.

**"major.minor.+"** (however many version number segments you have) will actually behave as "latest.integration" restricted to major.minor. Originally I thought it was restricted to releases but, no, it actually matches snapshots too.

**"[1.0,2.0)"** will actually behave list "latest.integration" within the range, too and will include snapshots, unlike I thought and commented above.

So, what I now don't know how to do is how to restrict a range or "1.+" to releases, but that is not my immediate problem (may be some hours from now, LOL).

*UPDATE*

One way to restrict versions to a range seems to be to mess with "Component metadata rules". Non-matching versions (those outside range) could be artificially declared non-releases. This is really ugly, though...

*UPDATE 2*

A part of my confusion was due to behavioural change between the old Gradle I was using and the new 2.1 one. Above is for 2.1 - old one I had (1.8) did NOT behave cleanly as per above.

Comment: How is "newer" defined? It's definitely not by actual timestamp. It's not by ASCII sorting either. It appears to be a filtered process, which ignores non-numeric containing versions. But it's not specified anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`[1.0,2.0)` already means either "latest anything" or "latest must-be-release" (I think the latter, but not entirely sure). The other isn't currently supported.

Comment: Thanks! My experience seems to be "latest release within range" ... as it does not seem to get -SNAPSHOTs. Is there any recommendation how I could custom-code the other?

Comment: Is there a way I can at least do something similar? Perhaps discover all versions, match them myself? Or something closer than that, such as semi-constrained (only one of the minimum, maximum) and I could do the other?

Comment: You'd have to write your own algorithm that resolves a version range to a version (including remote communication to list available versions in each repository etc.; I'm not aware of any public Gradle APIs that can help with this). Then you could hook that into Gradle's resolution process.

Comment: Is there a way to, at least, specify x.y.<latest>-SNAPSHOT somehow? I.e. not a true range, but has to maintain first two version numbers (major, minor)?

Comment: Actually, there seems to be more of an issue here... I started playing with this... and both "latest.integration" and "latest.release" find the same version even though there is a newer -SNAPSHOT (newer minor version than release).  This is a real problem.

Comment: ... in fact, when I removed the registration of repositories that contain releases and only kept the repo that only has snapshots, both latest.integration and latest.release resulted in "FAILED" .. whereas explicit snapshot version specification worked. Will try with updated version of Gradle.

Comment: Update resolved that issue... phew! latest.integration works better.